# Asymtotes to the the function: $y= \sqrt{{x^3-1\over x}}$ at x=0 there should be a vertical asymtote, but i don't know how to formally execute this..

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, functions

Asymtotes to the the function: $y= \sqrt{{x^3-1\over x}}$ at $x=0$ there should be a vertical asymtote , but i don't know how to formally execute this. When i try to find the limit, i get the square root of minus infinite and don't know how to regard that.I figure finding if there are any horizontal and diagonal asysmtotes should not be a problem.

Comment: You must have $\frac{x^3-1}{x}\geq 0$ for the square root to be defined, so for one thing $x\not\in(0,1)$.

Comment: You'll get a vertical asymptote on approaching from the left hand side to $x=0$. The function is not defined for $x \in [0,1)$

Comment: Other than that, asymptotes should be $y=-x$ and $x=0$ and $y=x$. Doesn't your textbook state definitions of having vertical/non-vertical asymptotes, and could you provide those definitions?

Comment: how about the right side of 1 ?

Comment: @BozoVulicevic: That is not actually an asymptote since $y(1)=0$ is finite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The domain of the expression $f(x)=\sqrt{\dfrac{x^3-1}{x}}$ is where
$$
\frac{x^3-1}{x}\ge0
$$
so it is $(-\infty,0)\cup[1,\infty)$. Since
$$
\lim_{x\to0^-}\sqrt{\frac{x^3-1}{x}}=\infty
$$
the function has a vertical asymptote at $0$. Not at $1$, because the function is continuous at $1$ (but not differentiable).

There are also oblique asymptotes:
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x}&=
\lim_{x\to\infty}\sqrt{\frac{x^3-1}{x^3}}=1
\\
\lim_{x\to\infty}(f(x)-x)&=
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{x^3-1}-\sqrt{x^3}}{\sqrt{x}}=0
\end{align}
Similarly,
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x}&=
\lim_{x\to-\infty}-\sqrt{\frac{x^3-1}{x^3}}=-1
\\
\lim_{x\to-\infty}(f(x)+x)&=
\lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac{\sqrt{x^3-1}-\sqrt{x^3}}{\sqrt{x}}=0
\end{align}
so $y=-x$ is an oblique asimptote at $-\infty$ and $y=x$.

[image]

Comment: How would you find the horizontal asymtotes to $f(x)=arctg{{X+1\over 2x-3}}$ ?

Comment: @BozoVulicevic Since $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x+1}{2x-3}=\frac{1}{2}$, the horizontal asymptote is $y=\arctan\frac{1}{2}$; the same at $-\infty$.

Comment: how did you get this limit?

Comment: i understand now..

Comment: @BozoVulicevic $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac{x+1}{2x-3}=\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac{1+1/x}{2-3/x}$

Comment: is the following true for all func5tions : $\lim\limits_{x\to c} f(g(x))= f(\lim\limits_{x\to c} g(x))$

Comment: @BozoVulicevic Surely if the function $f$ is continuous at $a=\lim\limits_{x\to x_0}g(x)$; it's possible to extend this to the case when the limit is $\infty$ or $-\infty$. So, for instance, if $\lim_{x\to x_0}g(x)=\infty$, then $\lim_{x\to x_0}\arctan g(x)=\pi/2$.

Comment: On last question, how about the aymtotes for (vertical in particular) $f(x)={1+ln|x|\over x(1-ln|x|)}$ ?

Comment: I dont know how to find the limit in that example

Comment: and when a function has a horizontal asymtote it does not have an oblique one ?

Comment: I keep getting an indefinite limit of (infinity over infinity)over infinity...

Comment: @BozoVulicevic Please, don't pile up questions in comments; open a new question explaining what you've done and you'll receive answers.